# How can I draw a grey border?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I want to draw a border.
However, when I finished the code, it displayed an error.
This is the code I wrote:

```
  <canvas id="painting" width="700" height="700"></canvas>

  <script>
    var colourCanvas = document.getElementById("colour");
    var colourctx = colourCanvas.getContext("2d");

    var widthColour = colourCanvas.width;
    var heightColour = colourCanvas.height;

    var blockSizeColour = 10;
    var widthInBlocksColour = widthColour / blocksSizeColour;
    var heightInBlocksColour = heightColour / blockSizeColour;

    var drawColourBorder = function (colour) {
      colourctx.fillStyle = colour;
      colourctx.fillRect(0, 0, widthColour, blockSizeColour));
      colourctx.fillRect(0, heightColour - blockSizeColour, widthColour, blockSizeColour);
      colourctx.fillRect(0, 0, blockSizeColour, heightColour);
      colourctx.fillRect(widthColour - blockSizeColour, 0, blockSizeColour, heightColour);
    };
    drawColourBorder("Gray");
  </script>
```

Is there any problems with it?
Also, the displayed error was:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
```

Also, you might see the

```
colourctx.fillRect(0, 0 widthColour, blockSizeColour));
```

has 2 ')'s.

I know, I changed it as soon as I shared this, but the error remains the same.

How can I change the code to have a Grey (700x700) border?

Answer (score 0):

```js
...
<canvas id="painting" width="700" height="700"></canvas>

  <script>
    var colourCanvas = document.getElementById("painting");
    var colourctx = colourCanvas.getContext("2d");

    var widthColour = colourCanvas.width;
    var heightColour = colourCanvas.height;

    var blockSizeColour = 10;
    var widthInBlocksColour = widthColour / blockSizeColour;
    var heightInBlocksColour = heightColour / blockSizeColour;

    var drawColourBorder = function (colour) {
      colourctx.fillStyle = colour;
      colourctx.fillRect(0, 0, widthColour, blockSizeColour);
      colourctx.fillRect(0, heightColour - blockSizeColour, widthColour, blockSizeColour);
      colourctx.fillRect(0, 0, blockSizeColour, heightColour);
      colourctx.fillRect(widthColour - blockSizeColour, 0, blockSizeColour, heightColour);
    };
    drawColourBorder("Gray");
  </script>
```

Comment: But after I changed the colourctx.fillRect(0, 0 widthColour, blockSizeColour)); to colourctx.fillRect(0, 0 widthColour, blockSizeColour); it still has an error. Other ways?

Comment: colourctx.fillRect(0, 0 ,widthColour, blockSizeColour);   you miss a ',' after 0

Comment: still doesn't work.... It said 'canvas' is not defined so I changed it. it still doesn't work.

Comment: that is so... i edit the whole code,see if it is worked.

Comment: @waiaan Please don't just post code in an answer without an explanation. Always add some text that explains what was wrong and what you did to correct it.